# Foundation data-alert box won't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I am using the zurb foundation and all is working well except for data-alert.  I am unable to close data-alert with the X.  In other posts, people say to add the $(document.foundation(); again after the data-alert div.  I have tried it with and without the second initialization.  Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.min.css">
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script> 
<script>
     $(document).foundation();
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-alert class="alert-box alert radius hide-for-print">You can't close this!!!<a href="#" class="close">&times;</a></div>

<script>
     $(document).foundation();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any help I can get on this..  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `data-alert` was not closing because `modernizr` wasn't included in your project.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xabivoqine/1/edit?html,console,output)**

Mostly this kind of errors you can solve by checking the console.

In console, It was showing the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Modernizr

Because foundation.min.js required modernizr to work

Comment: I added modernizr.js and it didn't help. Also  I have other projects that are working without modernizr.

Comment: Check the console and see if any error is there. Because in the jsbin it;s working. Else the error is not in this code, it's somewhere else which is preventing execution of js\